# Can the var value of a radio button be a string in Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to put the value of the var as a string on the radio button but I get this error:

```
var=IntVar()
new.R1=Radiobutton(new,text='masculino',variable=var,value='m',bg='pale goldenrod',width=30)

new.R1.pack(anchor=W)

_tkinter.TclError: expected floating-point number but got "f"
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course, just specify your var as a StringVar() instead of an IntVar(). Also i am not sure what your variable new is, the way you use it you would generally access functions in objects of classes or similar. I suggest you name your radiobutton variables something like radiobutton_one or give it a more descriptive name, but do not use dots. Have a look at my example here:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

my_var = StringVar(value="first radiobutton")
radio_button_one = Radiobutton(window, text="Test 1", variable=my_var, value="first radiobutton")
radio_button_one.pack()
radio_button_two = Radiobutton(window, text="Test 2", variable=my_var, value="second radiobutton")
radio_button_two.pack()


def radiobutton_callback():
    print(my_var.get())


some_button = Button(window, text="Get Value of radiobutton", command=radiobutton_callback)
some_button.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: the variable 'new' is the name of the window where the radiobuttons are going , but before i have the main window named 'menu'. Im a student and my teacher recommend me this site and this programme is like the final project of the semester and we have to use a grafic interface and i have to do a kind of cashier app for a shop . Thanks btw

Comment: You dont have to specify the root widget of your radiobutton by the variable name, new.R1 doesnt make any sense. You specify the root widget at your first argument when creating the Radiobutton, in your case by typing Radiobutton(new). Hope thats somewhat clear.